# Firebase Authentication using facebook and google signin not working when internet is turned off and turned back on

Tags: facebook, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a strange issue with firebase authentication. SigninCredential callback never gets called when I turn off and turn back on the internet. Only after a few hours(probably after 4 hours) callback gets triggered

```
    val mCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(mAccesstoken!!.token)
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(mCredential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { it ->
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                getCurrentUser(mFirebaseAuth.currentUser)
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.// unable to retrieve details of the user
                Log.w(
                    TAG,
                    "signInWithCredential:failure:: FirebaseAuthentication failed even though accesstoken present",
                    it.exception
                )
                Toast.makeText(
                    baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
```

If I do a fresh install of the app and perform a sign in it works properly provided that the internet is turned on while I try to login into the app

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I added an active internet condition before performing a login that fixed sign-in problem. check the internet available on the device then only perform the login

I did face another issue that is addOnCompleteListener never gets called because I was waiting on the main thread instead I used executor to perform the task on a background thread

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

First check for internet connection before executing the above code.